# Create a gzip file of a predetermined size

Tags: files, compression

I want to test an upload of files of content type `application/x-gzip` of various sizes ranging from 100 MB to 999 MB.

How can go I about creating `.gz` files of these predetermined sizes? If I do `dd if=/dev/zero of=somefile bs=1 seek=100`, the resultant file after zipping is usually very small.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- You can create a 10MB gzip file like this:

  ```
  head -c 10M /dev/urandom | gzip -1 >10m.gz
  ```

  This uses `urandom` to get a high-entropy stream of bytes: since
  this is incompressible, the gzipped version will be about the same
  size as the input.
- You can then catenate copies of your gzip file together:

  ```
  cat $(perl -e "print '10m.gz ' x 30") >300m.gz
  ```

  Thirty copies of the source file will be about 300MB, and 100
  copies will be about a gigabyte.

Comment: I had to use -c 10m instead of 10M. Rest was good. Thanks!

Comment: Can you concatenate several gzip files and get another gzip file with the concatenated data? That seems dodgy.

Comment: Yes, you can concatenate gzip files.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005114/fast-concatenation-of-multiple-gzip-files

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method. You can create  files by controlling the loop variable `filecount`. This creates random files of size between 100MB to 900 MB and `gzip`s them.

```
#!/bin/bash
filecount=0
while [ $filecount -lt 10 ]
do
filesize=$((RANDOM%9+1))
filesize=$(($filesize*104857600))
</dev/urandom head -c "$filesize" | gzip > /tmp/file${filecount}.$RANDOM.gz
((filecount++))
done
```

Comment: The output from `base64` is compressible by about 25%; I would recommend skipping the base64 bit and calling head directly on `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: @dhag thanks. I edited the answer to reflect that.